# Type-safe union in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, reflection, unions, gadt, data-kinds

Can I have a type-safe union (As in C's `union`) in Haskell? This is the best I tried, here `Variant`, named after C++'s `std::variant`:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}
{-# LANGUAGE KindSignatures #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeOperators #-}

module Emulation.CPlusPlus.Variant (
    Variant, singleton
) where

import Data.Type.Bool
import Data.Type.Equality
import Type.Reflection

data Variant :: [*] -> * where
    Singleton :: a -> Variant (a ': as)
    Arbitrary :: Variant as -> Variant (a ': as)

singleton :: (Not (bs == '[]) || a == b) ~ 'True => forall a b. a -> Variant (b ': bs)
singleton x = case eqTypeRep (typeRep :: TypeRep a) (typeRep :: TypeRep b) of
    Nothing    -> Arbitrary (singleton x)
    Just HRefl -> Singleton x
```

This produces error message as follows:

```
Prelude> :load Variant.hs
[1 of 1] Compiling Emulation.CPlusPlus.Variant ( Variant.hs, interpreted )

Variant.hs:19:14: error:
    • Could not deduce: (Not (bs == '[]) || (a0 == b0)) ~ 'True
      from the context: (Not (bs == '[]) || (a == b)) ~ 'True
        bound by the type signature for:
                   singleton :: forall (bs :: [*]) a b.
                                ((Not (bs == '[]) || (a == b)) ~ 'True) =>
                                forall a1 b1. a1 -> Variant (b1 : bs)
        at Variant.hs:19:14-85
      The type variables ‘a0’, ‘b0’ are ambiguous
    • In the ambiguity check for ‘singleton’
      To defer the ambiguity check to use sites, enable AllowAmbiguousTypes
      In the type signature:
        singleton :: (Not (bs == '[]) || a == b) ~ True =>
                     forall a b. a -> Variant (b : bs)
   |
19 | singleton :: (Not (bs == '[]) || a == b) ~ True => forall a b. a -> Variant (b ': bs)
   |              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Failed, no modules loaded.
```

I don't get how such ambiguity emerges.

Comment: your `forall a b` is to the right of `(Not (bs == '[]) || a == b)`, so the `a` and `b` you mention in `a -> Variant (b ': bs)` are independent of the `a` and `b` in the constraint.  That is, GHC reads this the same way it would `singleton :: (Not (bs == '[]) || a == b) ~ 'True => forall x y. x -> Variant (y ': bs)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The conventional names for the constructors are `Inl` and `Inr`:

```
import Data.Kind

data Sum :: [Type] -> Type where
  Inl :: a -> Sum (a : as) -- INject Left
  Inr :: !(Sum as) -> Sum (a : as) -- INject Right
```

The extra strictness in `Inr` is optional. Consider `Either a b`. This type has the values `undefined`, `Left undefined`, and `Right undefined`, along with all the other ones. Consider your `Variant [a, b]`. This has `undefined`, `Singleton undefined`, `Variant undefined`, and `Variant (Singleton undefined)`. There is one extra partially-undefined value that does not arise with `Either`. `Inr`'s strictness squashes `Inr undefined` and `undefined` together. This means you cannot have a value with only a "partially known" variant. All strictness annotations in the following are for "correctness." They squash out bottoms in places where you probably don't want bottoms.

Now, the signature of `singleton`, as pointed out by @rampion, has a use-before-definition error. It "ought" to be:

```
singleton :: forall a b.
             (Not (bs == '[]) || a == b) ~ True =>
             a -> Variant (b ': bs)
```

But that isn't quite right. If `a ~ b`, great, this works. If not, there is no way for the compiler to ensure that `a` is in `bs`, because you haven't constrained for that. This new signature still fails. For the most power, especially for future definitions, you'll want something like

```
-- Elem x xs has the structure of a Nat, but doubles as a proof that x is in xs
-- or: Elem x xs is the type of numbers n such that the nth element of xs is x
data Elem (x :: k) (xs :: [k]) where
  Here  :: Elem x (x : xs)
  There :: !(Elem x xs) -> Elem x (y : xs) -- strictness optional
-- boilerplate; use singletons or similar to dodge this mechanical tedium
-- EDIT: singletons doesn't support GADTs just yet, so this must be handwritten
-- See https://github.com/goldfirere/singletons/issues/150
data SElem x xs (e :: Elem x xs) where
  SHere  :: SElem x (x : xs) Here
  SThere :: SElem x xs e -> SElem x (y : xs) (There e)
class KElem x xs (e :: Elem x xs) | e -> x xs where kElem :: SElem x xs e
instance KElem x (x : xs) Here where kElem = SHere
instance KElem x xs e => KElem x (y : xs) (There e) where kElem = SThere kElem
demoteElem :: SElem x xs e -> Elem x xs
demoteElem SHere = Here
demoteElem (SThere e) = There (demoteElem e)

-- inj puts a value into a Sum at the given index
inj :: Elem t ts -> t -> Sum ts
inj Here x = Inl x
inj (There e) x = Inr $ inj e x

-- try to find the first index where x occurs in xs
type family FirstIndexOf (x :: k) (xs :: [k]) :: Elem x xs where
  FirstIndexOf x (x:xs) = Here
  FirstIndexOf x (y:xs) = There (FirstIndexOf x xs)
-- INJect First
-- calculate the target index as a type
-- require it as an implicit value
-- defer to inj
injF :: forall as a.
        KElem a as (FirstIndexOf a as) =>
        a -> Sum as
injF = inj (demoteElem $ kElem @a @as @(FirstIndexOf a as))
-- or injF = inj (kElem :: SElem a as (FirstIndexOf a as))
```

You can also just stick an `Elem` inside `Sum`:

```
data Sum :: [Type] -> Type where
  Sum :: !(Elem t ts) -> t -> Sum ts -- strictness optional
```

You may recover `Inl` and `Inr` as pattern synonyms

```
pattern Inl :: forall ts. () =>
               forall t ts'. (ts ~ (t : ts')) =>
               t -> Sum ts
pattern Inl x = Sum Here x

data Inr' ts = forall t ts'. (ts ~ (t : ts')) => Inr' (Sum ts')
_Inr :: Sum ts -> Maybe (Inr' ts)
_Inr (Sum Here _) = Nothing
_Inr (Sum (There tag) x) = Just $ Inr' $ Sum tag x
pattern Inr :: forall ts. () =>
               forall t ts'. (ts ~ (t : ts')) =>
               Sum ts' -> Sum ts
pattern Inr x <- (_Inr -> Just (Inr' x))
  where Inr (Sum tag x) = Sum (There tag) x
```

If you try some more, you can use huge amounts of `unsafeCoerce Refl` (to create "bogus" type equalities) to create an API like this:

```
import Numeric.Natural
-- ...
type role SElem nominal nominal nominal
-- SElem is a GMP integer
-- Elem is a nice GADT
-- Elem gives a nice experience at the type level
-- this allows functions like FirstIndexOf
-- SElem avoids using unary numbers at the value level
newtype SElem x xs e = SElem Natural
pattern SHere :: forall t ts e. () =>
                 forall ts'. (ts ~ (t:ts'), e ~ (Here :: Elem t (t:ts'))) =>
                 SElem t ts e
pattern SThere :: forall t ts e. () =>
                  forall t' ts' e'. (ts ~ (t':ts'), e ~ (There e' :: Elem t (t':ts'))) =>
                  SElem t ts' e' ->
                  SElem t ts e
-- implementations are evil and kinda long
-- you'll probably need this:
-- type family Stuck (k :: Type) :: k where {- no equations -}
-- pattern synonyms are incredibly restrictive, so they aren't very straightforward
-- currently GHC does not allow INLINEs on pattern synonyms, so this won't
-- compile down to simple integer expressions just yet, either :(
```

And then write

```
data Sum :: [Type] -> Type where
  Sum :: forall t ts (e :: Elem t ts). !(SElem t ts e) -> t -> Sum ts
```

which is close to a `struct` of an integer tag and a `union`, except said tag is a bit oversized.